# How to keep keyboard mapping after reboot?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

In order to remap my keyboard I use the following commands:

```
$ setxkbmap -layout fr -variant latin9 -option ''
$ setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps
$ printf "keycode  127 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock" > ~/.Xmodmap
$ xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap
```

After that, everything works as expected. However, when I reboot (I noticed the same behavior on two of my computers, one is on Lubuntu 20.04 and the other on Ubuntu 20.04), I have swapcaps instead of nocaps and keycode 127 has its original mapping.

How can I prevent reboot from changing my remapping?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Put Line number 1,2 and 4 on `~/.bash_profile`. Then each time you login, these will be executed. Line number 3 needs to be executed only once.

Comment: I added 1,2,4 to `~/.bash_profile` and rebooted. I still have swapcaps instead of nocaps and keycode 127 has its original mapping.

Comment: Did you check the Xmodmap file has the description `keycode  127 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock`? `cat ~/.Xmodmap`

Comment: Yes, `$ cat ~/.Xmodmap` gives `keycode  127 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lockc`. Surprisingly, on the last boot, it worked...

Comment: You will prefer ~ /.profile. ~/.bashrc is loaded only when you start an interactive terminal